# Is it possible to get the name of the active activity-alias?

Tags: applications

I am developing an application that has the ability to change the icon that is displayed in the launcher. I share the code that does this. I understand that this is not a forum for developers, so you can imagine that there are several icons in the application, but only one is always displayed in the launcher.

```
public static void setIcon(LauncherIcon icon) {
    Context ctx = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext;
    PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    for (LauncherIcon i : LauncherIcon.values()) {
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(i.getComponentName(ctx), i == icon ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

I wanted to write a command that would know which icon is currently active. This can just be determined by taking from somewhere a list of only active `activity-alias`es. Since the control in the code happens through the `PackageManager`, I assume that in the terminal this is possible with the `pm` utility. But I didn't find anything to help me. As I understand it, somehow through `pm` I can get a list of `activity-alias`es, and then for each get the properties `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` or `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` , which I specify in the code. If I find the property `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` then I should get the name of this `activity-alias`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if your app has package `com.company.Calc` and has two `activity-alias`: `com.company.MainActivity1` (default) and `com.company.MainActivity2` you can get current active `activity-alias` like this:

```
dumpsys package com.company.Calc | grep -A1 "enabledComponents" | grep "com.company" | grep -o '[^$(printf '\t') ].*' || echo "com.company.MainActivity1"
```